# Can USB-C PowerDelivery be restricted to manufacturers devices?

Tags: usb-c, power-delivery

I have recently searched for a new monitor. I'd like to have a single-cable setup via USB-C, so I need a monitor that supports PowerDelivery. I found a good match (from HP) but looking into reviews on it I read that the full potential of PowerDelivery (100 Watts) is only supported if the receiving device is from the same manufacturer as the monitor. For all other devices, the PowerDelivery is capped at 65W.

I called the support hotline to ask about it, but they couldn't help me. I know that communication happens between source and sink when charging via USB-C, as different voltage levels and currents are supported. But before today I never heard of a restriction on devices from a specific manufacturer.

I would much appreciate any insight into this matter. Maybe it is simply a situation of "we haven't tested it with other devices, but it should work well if the sink can handle 100W" and not a "we do not supply 100W"?

Comment: sounds like vendor lockin ... "if you stay within our ecosystem we can offer more". Its like what Apple does with BT, they don't technically break the spec but they make it hard for non-apple to work with apple

Comment: @Lens, I think there should be an apostrophe in your question title - either *manufacturer's* or *manufacturers'* depending on your meaning. It's confusing as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a good match (from HP) but looking into reviews on it I read that the full potential of PowerDelivery (100 Watts) is only supported if the receiving device is from the same manufacturer as the monitor. For all other devices, the PowerDelivery is capped at 65W.

Going from 60W (3A) to 100W (5A) requires special cabling.  Normally a device polls the cable (which must include an identifier indicating that it can safely run at 5A).  One possibility is that they only enable 5A if they see one of their own cables, or one of their own devices.  Alternatively, they may simply not have tested 5A on any other devices and so will not commit to it definitively working or not (or if this is just some reviewer they may have used the wrong cable type).